Reading an unknown extension object from OPC UA using gopcua
I am new to OPC and was trying to read from an OPC UA server in golang using gopcua library, but I encountered the following error:
StatusBadDataTypeIdUnknown (0x80110000) error.
I’m reading the data as follows
nodeID, err := ua.ParseNodeID(nodeIDStr)
    if err != nil {
        return domain.NodeValue{}, err
    }

    var resp *ua.ReadResponse

    resp, err = o.client.Read(ctx, &ua.ReadRequest{
        MaxAge:             2000,
        NodesToRead:        []*ua.ReadValueID{{NodeID: nodeID}},
        TimestampsToReturn: ua.TimestampsToReturnBoth,
    })

The type of data on the WinCC is displayed as  Binary Tag

However when I try to read it gives me the error
The extension object cannot be (de)serialized because the data type id is not recognized. StatusBadDataTypeIdUnknown (0x80110000)
I wonder if there is a way in OPC UA protocol to discover or get data types from the server? If there isn’t, how can I identify the data type and register it ?
Moreover if there is some other library or a way that can be helpful for reading unknown extension object.

Our OPC UA Cient SDK discovers custom types at runtime, and can decode them. So you can access individual fields from code, or convert it to JSON formatted text. But it is in C++, not Go.
https://onewayautomation.com/opcua-sdk
